# How do you simulate the effects of microgravity on plants?

Tags: simulation, plants

My team and I are working on planting in space. What equipment/techniques are used to simulate microgravity on earth for such experiments?

Comment: generally, to simulate microgravity for long term processes, the samples are slowly tumbled so there is no net effect.

Comment: Gravity is an inherent interaction of mass and spacetime. There is no material that can shield against it. But there are *techniques* to try to get around it, such as the tumbling technique @JCRM mentioned. Your question should address techniques, not materials. But no such technique truly simulates microgravity. If you tumble macroscopic plants, their structural parts (stems etc.) still get forces applied to them, and they respond with growth characteristics that have them survive the tumbling. For true microgravity you have to have freefall, and for long-period work you need to be in space!

Comment: Hi Joshua welcome to space! Biology Stack Exchange has several [questions about microgravity](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=microgravity) that you may find interesting. for example: [How would a plant sprout and grow in a zero gravity environment?)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/1101/27918) Also here in Space see [Can plants grow in microgravity?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1074/12102) and also [Have there been experiments in space to determine how plants grow without any gravitational or light cues for direction?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31762/12102)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clinostat   and Scientific American 1970 June article by CLStrong